# Поиск в таблице Google

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Как организовать поиск по совпадению с помощью скрипта?

**Пример:**

`A1="Текст поиска"`, из массива данных (`C1:F`). В `B1` нужно записать нужный ID из `C1:С`.

PS: Текст поиска должен быть не чувствительным к регистру

Answer (score 0):

Как простейший вариант:

1) Получить массив значений с помощью [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) или [getDisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues())

2) Пройтись по двумерному массиву [циклом](https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for) и проверять на совпадение с нужным каждый элемент массива (для нечувствительности к регистру применяйте метод [toLowerCase](http://javascript.ru/string/tolowercase)

3) После нахождения совпадения записать нужное значение в нужную ячейку с помощью [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))

**Profit!**

Comment: Немного не получается. Я ищу по части строки, а не по полному совпадению. Можно "код"? Я нашел, но не то... [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482143/google-scripts-search-spreadsheet-by-column-return-rows]